# Service Fabric tooling for Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 seems to be broken

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-service-fabric

I've installed the SF SDK 2.1.150 (VS2015), cloned the https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-getting-started and opened in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 running as admin. I was not able to select the WordCount application as a startup project:

[image]

Trying to create new project from the "Service Fabric Application" template, after clicking OK in the "New Project" dialog, I'm getting error message:

> Expected 1 export(s) with contract name
>   "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Shared.IShellService" but found 0
>   after applying applicable constraints.

I've tried to Repair the SDK components "Microsoft Azure Service Fabric 5.1.150.9590", "Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK 2.1.150.9590" and "Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio 2015 1.1.40531.2" using the Control Panel "Programs and Features" applet. I've uninstalled and reinstalled the SDK, rebooted the machine to no avail.

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Clearing the Visual Studio component cache according to the following steps helped:

https://github.com/Codealike/Codealike-KnowledgeBase/blob/master/clear-visual-studio-component-cache.md :

```
On Visual Studio 2015

1. Close Visual Studio (ensure devenv.exe is not present in the Task Manager)
2. Delete the %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache directory
3. Restart Visual Studio.
```

Comment: Thanks :) was looking for the same.

Comment: Thanks! found this after several hours of troubleshooting... This fixed an issue I was seeing when trying to load an existing service fabric project after upgrading my Azure SDK. "this project is not compatible with the current edition of visual studio"

Comment: This also fixed it for VS2017 for me, I cleared it from all the 15.0_* folders.